# Handling data with lists

Tags: c#

Is this bad practice? Or is it completely fine to do this

```
private readonly List<KeyValuePair<GameType, KeyValuePair<string, string>>> _tempStats = new List<KeyValuePair<GameType, KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();
```

GameType is an enumerator by the way.

I have data that I am downloading from a table that has a few different GameTypes with two strings associated with them. So it will parse the data and determines what GameType to assign it, and it finds the tables Key and it's Value. And it works, it stores the information and I am able to retrieve it with no problems, but it just seems like having a list of a KeyValuePair with a KeyValuePair isn't right, but maybe it is. Would using a tuple be a better approach?

My current usage of the list

```
    private void ParseNodeText(string nText, GameType gmode)
    {
        _tempStats.Clear();
        var reader = new StringReader(nText);
        while((nText = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            nText = nText.Replace(" ", "");
            if (nText == "")
            {
                continue;
            }
            string statType = Regex.Replace(nText, "[^A-Za-z]", "");
            string statValue = Regex.Replace(nText, "[^0-9]", "");
            //  Console.WriteLine(gmode + " : Found line with Type of {0} and a value of {1}",statType,statValue);
            _tempStats.Add(new KeyValuePair<GameType, KeyValuePair<string, string>>(gmode, new KeyValuePair<string, string>(statType, statValue)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the keys unique? If so, how about a `Dictionary`?

Comment: Why don't you create a Game class out of those data and have that class in a single list instead? You have 2 fields and an enumerator...

Comment: The table I am getting the data from is dynamic, and there are about 40 different keys which could be found and the values are dynamic as well ranging between 1~10,000(roughly).

Comment: For future reference, you can indent your entire code block by 4 spaces to have it be properly formatted as a block code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution is fine, but not that good readable.

You could do something like this:

```
private readonly List<GameStats> _tempStats = new List<GameStats>();
```

and GameStats is a own written simple Class:

```
public class GameStats
{
    public GameType Type { get; set; }

    public string StatType { get; set; }

    public string StatValue { get; set; }

    public GameStats(GameType gameType, string statType, string statValue)
    {
        this.Type = gameType;
        this.StatType = statType;
        this.StatValue = statValue;
    }
}
```

and add it to your list like:

```
_tempStats.Add(new GameStats(gmode, statType, statValue));
```

i think, this looks good and will do it.